# ground wire to panel box

Tags: electrical

I have two wires from the power supply to my main panel and no ground electrode wire; how do I connect the ground wire from the main panel to the ground rod? The circuits? the receptacles? Also, how do I wire the panel box? now this what I did, I connected the neutral to the bus bar then connected the ground wire to its bus bar and linked a wire from the neutral bus to the ground bus. I took a wire from the bus bar of ground to the ground rod. what is your advice to these connections.

Comment: It sounds as if you do not have too much experience with wiring. Setting up a main panel is usually best left to either a professional or others who have had a good deal of experience. There are some serious risks, both immediately and long term.

Comment: Honestly, your question is FAR too vague. Either re-word it to make more sense, or better yet, get a pro in there to fix you up. What is your level of experience with working on a breaker panel, and wiring in general?

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have one, you need a [grounding terminal](http://www.homedepot.com/s/grounding%20terminal?NCNI-5&gsitesearch).

Wiring a panel is not difficult, but definitely check your local code to make sure that panel wiring isn't required to be done by a licensed electrician.

All of your other questions can be answered with simple Google searches. You should really do research on your own before asking very broad questions.

Comment: Down voting without commenting as to why is unacceptable. Own up to your opinion.